# how to remove space in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm checking two strings whether it is same or not. I used trim(), replaceAll() to clear space in string but still it is showing 21, 22, 23 like that, I want that string to be like
21,22,23 so that I can verify it.

change this 21, 22, 23 into 21,22,23

Comment: `replaceAll` returns a new "replaced" string, have you tried checking that ?

Comment: Also consider including sample code that will reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll` returns a new string and first string does not change.

`trim` removes leading or trailing whitespace.

This works!

```
void main() {
  String s = '21, 22, 23';
  String s2 = s.replaceAll(' ', '');
  print(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use regex

> ```
> String s1 = " your string will be clear \f   from all  spaces   ";
> print(s1.replaceAll(new RegExp("[ \n\t\r\f]"), '')); 
> //yourstringwillbeclearfromallspaces
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text = '21, 22, 23';
text = text.replaceAll(', ', ',');
print(text); //'21,22,23'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
String removeTextSpaces(String value) {
    String stringResult = "";
    value.split(' ').map((e) => stringResult += e);
    for (var e in value.split(' ')) {
        stringResult += e;
    }
    return stringResult;
}
```

Comment: you can use also ---> `String removeTextSpaces(String value) => value.replaceAll(' ', '');`